# Progress bar listview tiem Android

Tags: android, android-listfragment

I'm trying to implement a `ProgressBar` inside `ListFragment` items, my application works like this,

1. App is notified through GCM to download 2 files
2. The app will start a thread to download the files
3. The thread will update the DB by adding a new field with the file name and the file URL to be
   downloaded, and I have a field in the DB that shows if the     the
   file is download successful or not.
4. The thread will be updating a
       global variable with the progress of each file with the     same
       name saved in DB
5. when the download completes, the thread will
       update the row with "download completed" 
           and notify the dataset which will reload the cursor (cursor loader)
6. The list fragment will show the item as downloaded.

Now, on the `ListFragment` side, the app could be running which makes the `ListFragment` visible, in this case how can I get the progress of the item being downloaded? Should I poll from the BindView? something like below, which is really not good approach.

```
while(true)
 {
   updateProgressBar(globalVar.DownloadProgress);
 }
```

Or should I notify the item about the progress? which I'm not sure how to do that, and I don't want to reload the cursor.

Please let me know if I'm not clear enough.

Comment: ok your Download-progress is another context than your listView right? so you havent access to a callback from your download-client?

Comment: the download thread is handler thread.

Comment: Do you know in advance the size of the file? do you save that information in the database?

Comment: Let's say I do? what do you have in mind?

Answer (score 0):

Since a download requires an internet connection, you cannot do this on the main thread. If you are using an `AsyncTask` for the multi-threading, then you simply need to override `onProgressUpdate()`. If you aren't using `AsyncTask`, I suggest you consider modifying your code to do so.